# How to set WooCommerce sorting dropdown $orderby selection as a body class?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My goal is to get the current WooCommerce sorting option selected, such as `websitename.com/?orderby=popularity` and set whatever the current query selection is as a body class. (Ideally something like `body class="popularity"`).

In the example below I am using if/elseif statements. I attempted this with a switch operator as well as simply using `global $orderby`. I haven't been able to find any example covering this question and feeling quite stuck so I appreciate any help.

Thank you. Here is my current documentation:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'gaz_wc_sorting_as_body_class' );

function gaz_wc_sorting_as_body_class( $class ){

    $orderby_value = $_GET['orderby'];

    if ($orderby_value === 'popularity') {
        array( ' popular '  => $class);
    } elseif ($orderby_value === 'date') {
        array( ' recent '  => $class);
    } elseif ($orderby_value === 'price') {
        array( ' cost-lo-hi '  => $class);
    } elseif ($orderby_value === 'price-desc') {
        array( ' cost-hi-lo '  => $class);
    } else {
        array( 'sort-clear '  => $class);
    }
    return $class;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - Woo hoo!
[Bhautik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6469645/bhautik) is correct about `array_push($class, 'string');` Though it wasn't working for me until I changed the *singular quotations* around the string to push into **double quotations**. Using **double quotations**, this documentation using array_push() works like a charm!

Though, I took it one step further to make the function dynamic for orderby queries by pushing the $orderby_value as the class name pushed to the body class array.

```
function gaz_wc_sorting_as_body_class( $class ){
    
 $orderby_value = $_GET['orderby'];
    
    if ( $orderby_value ) {
        array_push( $class, $orderby_value );
    }

  return $class;

}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'gaz_wc_sorting_as_body_class' );
```

For anyone interested in using static classes pushed to the body HTML element, here is my documentation that worked with Bhautik's solution:

```
function gaz_wc_sorting_as_body_class( $class ){

    $orderby_value = $_GET['orderby'];
    
    if ( $orderby_value === 'popularity' ) {
        // Required DOUBLE quotations (not singluar.)
        array_push($class, "popular" );
    } elseif ( $orderby_value === 'date' ) {
        array_push($class, "recent");
    } elseif ( $orderby_value === 'price' ) {
        array_push($class, "cost-lo-hi");
    } elseif ( $orderby_value === 'price-desc' ) {
        array_push($class, "cost-hi-lo");
    } else {
        array_push($class, "sort-clear");
    }
    
    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'gaz_wc_sorting_as_body_class' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can push your class name to the `$class` array. You can use the `array_push` function. try the below code.

```
function gaz_wc_sorting_as_body_class( $class ){

    $orderby_value = $_GET['orderby'];

    if ( $orderby_value === 'popularity' ) {
        array_push( $class, 'popular' );
    } elseif ( $orderby_value === 'date' ) {
        array_push($class, 'recent');
    } elseif ( $orderby_value === 'price' ) {
        array_push($class, 'cost-lo-hi');
    } elseif ( $orderby_value === 'price-desc' ) {
        array_push($class, 'cost-hi-lo');
    } else {
        array_push($class, 'sort-clear');
    }
    
    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'gaz_wc_sorting_as_body_class' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tested using array_push() reluctantly without success. Though since testing using your code, I used ` echo "<script>console.log('Orderby: " . $orderby_value . "' );</script>"; ` which retrieves the correct sorting query. Encouraging to see that ` $orderby_value = $_GET['orderby']; ` is working. Though, when using ` console.log() ` with ` $class ` it returns nothing in the console. I'm currently investigating why ` $class ` is not assigning / why it is not working. I'm continuing to test with array_push() as I think that is a great suggestion, thanks again.

Comment: Can you share the site URL? and, Where did you put this code?

Comment: Since my last comment, I have been able to use console.log to decipher the issue with $class within each if statement like so: ` if ( $orderby_value === 'popularity' ) {
    echo "<script>console.log('IF $ Orderby = popularity: " . $orderby_value . "' );</script>";
    array_push( $class, 'popular' );
    echo "<script>console.log('array push popular to $ class: " . $class . "' );</script>";
} ` using this markup, the console prints: ` IF $ Orderby = popularity: popularity
array push popular to $ class: Array. ` So, array push is working but is returning "Array" but not a single value?

Comment: Yes `$class` is an array that's why it's returning array.

Comment: @Rockstar Does it work? I can see a class in `body`.

Comment: I did get it to work for me, thank you for asking. For me, I had to change the quotations from singular to double within the push array. I posted about it below. Thank you again, array_push() was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'gaz_wc_sorting_as_body_class' );

function gaz_wc_sorting_as_body_class( $class ){
    
     $class = array('orderby' => '', 'order' => '');
     if (self::isActive()) {
         $query = new WC_Query();
         $class = $query->get_catalog_ordering_args();
     }
     return $class;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer?